# How to convert a Python datetime object into timestamp without time and backwards?

Tags: python, datetime, time, timestamp

I am making a timestamp out of a datetime object without minutes, seconds and so on:

```
import datetime
import time
import pytz
today_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow')).replace(hour=0, minute=0,second=0, microsecond=0).timestamp()
```

And as a result I get:

```
1506546000.0
```

Then I am making a timestamp out of a string type object:

```
str_to_time = time.strptime('28.09.17', '%d.%m.%y')
time_to_timestamp = time.mktime(str_to_time)
```

And I get:

```
1506556800.0
```

I put the today's date in a string. Why these numbers are different?

Comment: If you do `time.tzname` locally, is it equivalent to 'Europe/Moscow' timezone?

Answer (score 0):

`time.strptime` uses whatever timezone it inherited from the process that started the `python` process.  Likely the timezone that was set when python was launched is not `Europe/Moscow`, but `UTC`. Did you have `TZ=UTC` set when launching the python interpreter?

```
today_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('UTC')).replace(hour=0, minute=0,second=0, microsecond=0).timestamp()
1506556800.0
```